# Jenkins Pipeline OWASP Dependency Check Failing Build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, owasp

This is my current configuration. Have a groovy script which executes pipeline stages and have included a stage to execute the dependency check.

Currently the build fails because of "exit code 242"
[image: error-message]

Below is my groovy script

```
stage('VT Dependency Check') {
                steps {
                    dependencyCheck additionalArguments: ''' 
                    -o "./" 
                    -s "./"
                    -f "ALL" 
                    --prettyPrint
                    --failOnCVSS 10''', odcInstallation: 'VT-Dependancy-Check'

                    dependencyCheckPublisher pattern: 'dependency-check-report.xml'
                }
            }
```

This is just a proof of concept so I would just like to get the build to pass

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a catch-error block surrounding the dependencyCheck.

```
stage('VT Dependency Check') {
    steps {
      catchError {
          dependencyCheck additionalArguments: ''' 
          -o "./" 
          -s "./"
          -f "ALL" 
          --prettyPrint
          --failOnCVSS 10''', odcInstallation: 'VT-Dependancy-Check'

          dependencyCheckPublisher pattern: 'dependency-check-report.xml'
        }    
    }
}
```